# Creating a Flowable that emits items at a limited rate to avoid the need to buffer events

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, rx-java2

I've got a data access object that passes each item in a data source to a consumer:

```
public interface Dao<T> {
    void forEachItem(Consumer<T> item);
}
```

This always produces items in a single threaded way - I can't currently change this interface.

I wanted to create a `Flowable` from this interface:

```
private static Flowable<String> flowable(final Dao dao) {
    return Flowable.create(emitter -> {
        dao.forEachItem(item ->
                emitter.onNext(item));
        emitter.onComplete();
    }, ERROR);
}
```

If I use this `Flowable` in a situation where the processing takes longer than the rate at which items are emitted then I understandably get a missing back pressure exception as I am using `ERROR` mode:

```
    Dao<String> exampleDao =
            itemConsumer ->
                    IntStream.range(0, 1_000).forEach(i ->
                            itemConsumer.accept(String.valueOf(i)));

    flowable(exampleDao)
            .map(v -> {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                return "id:" + v;
            })
            .blockingSubscribe(System.out::println);
```

I don't wish to buffer items - seems like this could lead to exhausting memory on very large data sets - if the operation is significantly slower than the producer.

I was hoping there would be a backpressure mode that would allow the emitter to block when passed next/completion events when it detects back pressure but that does not seem to be the case?

In my case as I know that the dao produces items in a single threaded way I thought I would be able to do something like:

```
  dao.forEachItem(item -> {
    while (emitter.requested() == 0) {
      waitABit();
    }         
    emitter.onNext(item)
  });
```

but this seems to hang forever.

How wrong is my approach? :-) Is there a way of producing items in a way that respects downstream back pressure given my (relatively restrictive) set of circumstances?

I know I could do this with a separate process writing to a queue and then write a Flowable based on consuming from that queue- would that be the preferred approach instead?

Comment: The problem is with the dao's callback way of emitting items. Unless you can backpressure that, for example, by telling that forEachItem should return at most N items, you are out of options (as callstack blocking from within the callback often leads to deadlock).

Comment: I'm bit surprised that blocking in the FlowableOnSubscribe would lead to deadlock: would have thought it would only be accessed by one thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the part of the Flowable, especially the part with `Supscription.request(long)`. I hope that gets you on the right way.

---

The `TestProducer`from this example produces `Integer`objects in a given range and pushes them to its `Subscriber`. It extends the `Flowable<Integer>` class. For a new subscriber, it creates a `Subscription` object whose `request(long)` method is used to create and publish the Integer values.

It is important for the `Subscription` that is passed to the `subscriber` that the `request()` method which calls `onNext()`on the subscriber can be recursively called from within this `onNext()` call. To prevent a stack overflow, the shown implementation uses the `outStandingRequests` counter and the `isProducing` flag.

```
class TestProducer extends Flowable<Integer> {
    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestProducer.class);
    final int from, to;

    public TestProducer(int from, int to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    @Override
    protected void subscribeActual(Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) {
        subscriber.onSubscribe(new Subscription() {

            /** the next value. */
            public int next = from;
            /** cancellation flag. */
            private volatile boolean cancelled = false;
            private volatile boolean isProducing = false;
            private AtomicLong outStandingRequests = new AtomicLong(0);

            @Override
            public void request(long n) {
                if (!cancelled) {

                    outStandingRequests.addAndGet(n);

                    // check if already fulfilling request to prevent call  between request() an subscriber .onNext()
                    if (isProducing) {
                        return;
                    }

                    // start producing
                    isProducing = true;

                    while (outStandingRequests.get() > 0) {
                        if (next > to) {
                            logger.info("producer finished");
                            subscriber.onComplete();
                            break;
                        }
                        subscriber.onNext(next++);
                        outStandingRequests.decrementAndGet();
                    }
                    isProducing = false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void cancel() {
                cancelled = true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The Consumer in this example extends `DefaultSubscriber<Integer>` and on start and after consuming an Integer requests the next one. On consuming the Integer values, there is a little delay, so the backpressure will be built up for the producer.

```
class TestConsumer extends DefaultSubscriber<Integer> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestConsumer.class);

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        request(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Integer i) {
        logger.info("consuming {}", i);
        if (0 == (i % 5)) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                // can be ignored, just used for pausing
            }
        }
        request(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
        logger.error("error received", throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        logger.info("consumer finished");
    }
}
```

in the following main method of a test class the producer and consumer are created and wired up:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        final TestProducer testProducer = new TestProducer(1, 1_000);
        final TestConsumer testConsumer = new TestConsumer();

        testProducer
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.single())
                .blockingSubscribe(testConsumer);

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When running the example, the logfile shows that the consumer runs continuously, while the producer only gets active when the internal Flowable buffer of rxjava2 needs to be refilled.

Comment: Thanks. Based on that example, I don't think what I want to do is possible without another process populating a blocking queue which is started when the subscription is made. `request(long)` would then consume items from the queue.